# C# scale and crop avatar image

Tags: c#

I trying to take user user uploaded image to scale and crop for use as an 250px x 250px avatar image, based on 3 rules:

1. If uploaded image is square, resize to 250px x 250px
2. If uploaded image is landscape orientation, scale height to 250px and width proportionately and center crop window horizontally.
3. If uploaded image is portrait orientation, scale width to 250px and height proportionately and center crop window vertically.

The resizing seems to be working, but the saved image does not seem to be getting cropped to a square?

```
        public static Image ScaleImage(Image image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
    {
        //Square
        if (image.Width == image.Height)
        {
            var newImage = new Bitmap(maxWidth, maxHeight);
            return newImage;
        }

        //Landscape
        else if (image.Width > image.Height)
        {
            var ratioY = (double)maxHeight / image.Height;

            var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratioY);
            var newHeight = maxHeight;

            var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);

            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
            {
                graphics.DrawImage(image, ((newWidth - maxWidth) / 2), 0, maxWidth, maxHeight);
            }

            return newImage;
        }
        //Portrait
        else
        {
            var ratioX = (double)maxWidth / image.Width;

            var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratioX);
            var newWidth = maxWidth;

            var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);

            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
            {
                graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, ((newHeight - maxHeight) / 2), newWidth, newHeight);
            }

            return newImage;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Your `graphics.DrawImage` calls aren't consistent, plus I'm not sure your new size calculations are correct. I've tried running them in a console app that just does the size calculations and the calculated dimension always comes out as more than 250.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used the Drawing API's but you don't seem to be resizing the images when they are already square.

Try this for the square block:

```
//Square
if (image.Width == image.Height)
{
    var newImage = new Bitmap(maxWidth, maxHeight);

    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
    {
        graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    }

    return newImage;
}
```

I would also suggest looking at http://imageresizing.net/